# Formatting ZonedDateTime according to locale

Tags: java, date, formatting

I have a ZonedDateTime object that I'd like to format according to a given Locale. I.e. in the US, I'd like the format to be "M-dd-yy", but in the UK it should  be "dd-M-yy".

What is the best way to do this given a specified locale?

Comment: Store your format pattern in a [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Comment: See for example [Internationalization and Localization in Java 8: Date and Time](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-localization#date-and-time) on Baeldung.

Answer (score 2):

The *java.time* classes can [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) the generation of text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mUz9t4).

> jeudi 10 juin 2021 à 18 h 16 min 51 s heure avancée des Rocheuses

If you want the date-only as seen in British style, extract a `LocalDate`, and localize with `Locale.UK`.

```
myZdt
.toLocalDate()
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate(
        FormatStyle.SHORT
    )
    .withLocale( 
        Locale.UK
    )
)
```

> 11/06/2021

But both Java 16 and the Wikipedia page [*Date and time notation in the United Kingdom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_Kingdom) disagree with your statement that:

> in the UK it should be "dd-M-yy"

Instead, Wikipedia claims UK style is DD/MM/YY, while Java 16 outputs a four-digit year. In my experience, a two-digit year causes nothing  but confusion; I highly recommend always using 4-digit years.

If you want to force a pattern, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)).